# Hosting <10gb of read-only data with reasonably fast but cheap access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-redshift, psql

tl;dr

I've currently got a PostGresQL database with about 10gb of data. This data is "archived" data- so it won't ever be changing, but I do need the data to be queryable/searchable/available for reading in the cheapest method possible for my Rails app.

Details:

I'm running a Digital Ocean server, but this is a no-profit project, so keeping costs low is essential. I'm currently using a low-end droplet `4 GB Memory / 40 GB Disk / SFO2 - Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64`
Querying this data/loading the pages it's used on can take a significant amount of time occasionally. Some pages timeout because they take over a minute to load. (Given, those are very large pages, but still)
I've been looking at moving the database over to Amazon RedShift, but the base prices seem large- as they're aimed at MUCH larger projects than mine.

Is my best bet to try to put more and more into making the queries small and only rendering small bits at a time? Even basic pages have a long query time because the server is slowed down so much. Or is there a method similar to RedShift that will allow me to quickly query the data while also storing it externally for a reasonable price?

Comment: I did not downvote you, but usually question about programming get more interest on SO. This question may be opinionated or not relevant for ruby on rails, maybe more for the system administration... those specialized on AWS or Digital Ocean

Comment: Thanks for that. :) I'll try one of those instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Amazon S3 and Amazon Athena. S3 is a super simple storage where you can dump your data in text files and Athena is a service that provides SQL-like interface to data stored on S3. S3 is super cheap and Athena has per runtime cost. Since you said your data isn't going to change and is going to be queried rarely it's a good solution.  Check this out: [9 Things to Consider When Choosing Amazon Athena](https://blog.openbridge.com/9-things-to-consider-when-choosing-amazon-athena-78a4d7157ff)

Comment: Agreed, this would work well as a low cost solution for occasional queries against 10GB of data. If you can convert your data to parquet format then the cost could be minimised. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html